# Different TTFB value on Chrome vs Web Vitals

Tags: next.js, web-performance, web-vitals, time-to-first-byte

I am noticing different TTBF values in Chrome network tab vs logged by WebVitals. Ideally it should be exactly same value, but sometimes seeing large difference as much as 2-3 seconds for certain scenarios.

I am using Next.js and using [reportWebVitals](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/measuring-performance/) to log respective performance metrics.

Here is a [sample repo](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-web-vitals-whpvq?file=/pages/_app.js), [app url](https://whpvq.sse.codesandbox.io/) and screenshots for reference.

Using `performance.timing.responseStart - performance.timing.requestStart` is returning more appropriate value than relying on WebVitals TTFB value.

Any idea what could be going wrong? Is is a bug on WebVitals and I shouldn't be using it or mistake at my end in consuming/logging the values?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number provided by `reportWebVitals` (and the underlying library [`web-vitals`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals)) is generally considered the correct TTFB in the web performance community (though to be fair, there are some differences in implementation across tools).

I believe DevTools labels that smaller number "Waiting (TTFB)" as an informal hint to the user what that "waiting" is to give it context and because it usually is the large majority of the TTFB time.

However, from a user-centric perspective, time-to-first-byte should really include all the time from when the user starts navigating to a page to when the server responds with the first byte of that page--which will include time for DNS resolution, connection negotiation, redirects (if any), etc. DevTools does include at least some information about that extra time in that screenshot, just separated into various periods above the ostensible TTFB number (see the "Queueing", "Stalled", and "Request Sent" entries).

Generally the [Resource Timing spec](https://w3c.github.io/resource-timing/) can be used as the source of truth for talking about web performance. It places [time 0 as the start of navigation](https://w3c.github.io/resource-timing/#terminology.):

> Throughout this work, all time values are measured in milliseconds since the start of navigation of the document [[HR-TIME-2](https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time-2/)]. For example, the start of navigation of the document occurs at time 0.

And then [defines `responseStart`](https://w3c.github.io/resource-timing/#dom-performanceresourcetiming-responsestart) as

> The time immediately after the user agent's HTTP parser receives the first byte of the response

So `performance.timing.responseStart - performance.timing.navigationStart` by itself is the browser's measure of TTFB (or `performance.getEntriesByType('navigation')[0].responseStart` in the newer Navigation Timing Level 2 API), and that's the number `web-vitals` [uses for TTFB](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals/blob/b673a8598f7be5c14571586d43545587c54e0a3b/src/getTTFB.ts#L55-L60) as well.